# Regex find pattern between blocks

Tags: php, regex, pcre, templating

I'm building a templating engine in PHP (Django like) that replaces everything between `{{ }}` with its related data. Right now I'm able to do that, but I'm facing a situation that requires a replacement only between blocks, such as `{% for y in x %}` loop blocks and ignores all brackets that are not in between them.

I was able to somewhat get some results in [this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/LjrRge/1) but only getting the first `{{ }}` of each block. What I want to do is to match all `{{ }}` in each block, excluding the ones that are outside.

Comment: any reason you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @rtfm learning purposes?

Comment: There's recursive regexen for that. But given that syntactic complexity and your likely experience, this doesn't seem very advisable. Investigate proper tokenization/parsing approaches, and then give up and use an existing template engine.

Comment: @mario not very welcoming, but I'll have a look into recursive regex... thanks.

Comment: It's an interesting topic of course. But generally a bit too broad for an SO question. Extracting the matching block placeholders is at best 20% of the task. You could still use a regex. But for relating start and end scopes, you'll better use a state machine / lil' interpreter anyway.

Comment: @mario Sometimes I feel I'm overcomplicating myself. Regex is perfect for simple tasks like simple matches and replacements but when I face problems like this I literally cry. As I said before, I'm new to regex and I want to have this done like that for learning purposes, but I'm really open to see other options to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Not the link I was looking for, but see those for some quick starting points/alternatives: [Dirt-simple PHP templates... can this work without \`eval\`?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3930053), [How to catch nested {% if ... %}{% endif %} statments with regex](//stackoverflow.com/q/28392033), [Regular expression for template engine?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18027607), [Read template with nested loops by regex](//stackoverflow.com/q/15189596)

Comment: Basic lexer: [PHP regex capture template tags and if statement tags](//stackoverflow.com/q/48271912) (that's where you're going...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For learning purposes (very good!) you have several possibilities:

1. A multi-step approach (easier to comprehend and to maintain):
2. An overall regex solution (more complicated & possibly more "fancy")

---

Ad 1)

Match the blocks with the following expression (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/LjrRge/3)):

```
{%\ for.*?%}
(?s:.+?)
{%\ endfor.*?%}
```

And look for pairs of `{{...}}` in **each block** with:

```
{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}
```

In `PHP`, this could be:

```
<?php
$data = <<<DATA
{% for user in users %}
   Hello, {{ user.name }}, you are {{ user.age }} {{ user.name }}
ssssssssssssssssssssss {{ user.name }}
sdsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
{% endfor %}

{% for dog in dogs %}
   Your dog is {{ dog.age }} and likes {{ dog.food }}.
{% endfor %}
wwww
{{ user.name }}
DATA;

$block = '~
            {%\ for.*?%}
            (?s:.+?)
            {%\ endfor.*?%}
            ~x';

$variable = '~{{\s*(.+?)\s*}}~';

if (preg_match_all($block, $data, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if (preg_match_all($variable, $match[0], $variables, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            print_r($variables);
        }

    }
}
?>
```

---

Ad 2)

Match all of the variables in question with an overall expression. Here, you'll need `\G` (which matches at the position of the last match) and some lookaheads (see [**a demo for this one at regex101.com as well**](https://regex101.com/r/LjrRge/4)):

```
(?:{%\ for.+?%}
|
\G(?!\A)
)
(?s:(?!{%).)*?\K
{{\s*(?P<variable>.+?)\s*}}
```

Now let's demystify this expression:

```
(?:{%\ for.+?%}
|
\G(?!\A)
)
```

Here, we want to either match `{%\ for.+?%}` (we need the `\` as we are in verbose mode) **or** at the position of the last match with `\G`. Now, the truth is, `\G` either matches at the position of the last match or the very beginning of the string. We do not want the latter, hence the neg. lookahead `(?!\A)`.

The next part

```
(?s:(?!{%).)*?\K
```

kind of does a "fast forward" to the interesting parts in question.

Broken down, this says

```
(?s:        # open a non-capturing group, enabling the DOTALL mode
    (?!{%). # neg. lookahead, do not overrun {% (the closing tag)
)*?         # lazy quantifier for the non-capturing group
\K          # make the engine "forget" everything to the left
```

Now, the rest is easy:

```
{{\s*(?P<variable>.+?)\s*}}
```

It's basically, the same construct as for ad 1).

Again, in `PHP`, this could be:

```
<?php

$regex = '~
            (?:{%\ for.+?%}
            |
            \G(?!\A)
            )
            (?s:(?!{%).)*?\K
            {{\s*(?P<variable>.+?)\s*}}
            ~x';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $data, $variables)) {
    print_r($variables[1]);
}
?>
```

---

With all that said, it's generally a good idea to actually learn more complex patterns but not to reinvent the wheel on the other hand - there's always someone smarter than you & me who has probably taken into account several edge cases, etc.